# How to bulk update database if the new values are in array? php

Tags: php, mysql, bulkupdate, multiple-records

I am trying to do an UPDATE statement for multiple records for the edit function. The page has multiple rows that requires to be updated. I am not sure how to construct the statement if the parameter passed is an array.

```
arr_items[[arr_items2]] </br>
arr_items[[value1, value2, value3, value4], [value1, value2, value3, value4]]
```

I tried different bind_param also but it won't work.

edit-view.php

```
$dao5->modify($arr_items)
```

DAO.php

```
public function modify($arr_items) {
        $sql = 'update table set 
                column3=:???(supposedly value3) 
                column4=:???(supposedly value4) 
                where column1=:???(supposedly value1) and column2=:???(supposedly value2);      

        $values = $arr_items;

        for ($i=0; $i < count($values); $i++){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        }

        $connMgr = new ConnectionManager();           
        $conn = $connMgr->getConnection();

       call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $values);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

> Error Message:  ``` Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   prepare() on null in C:

Answer (score 0):

after experimenting the sql should be as per below and loop inside the statement to modify each record.

```
       $sql = 'update table set column3=:value3, column4=:value4 where column1=:value1 and column2=:value2 ';      

        $values = $arr_items;

        for ($i=0; $i<count($values); $i++){
            $query_p = array(':value3'=> $arr_items[$i][2], ':value4' => $arr_items[$i][3], ':value1' => $arr_items[$i][0], ':value2' => $arr_items[$i][1]);

            $stmt->execute($query_p);
        }
```